# What is this Tiger tank wingman UGV?

Tags: world-war-two, identification, ww2-european-theater, tanks

Schneider, *Tiger Battalion 507*: "For some time it was expected that in action every Tiger commander would ‘pull the strings’ of two midget panzers loaded with explosives. The idea was eventually rejected as crazy." These are called "remote-controlled ‘P4’ panzers"
and "radio controlled P4 tanks".

[image]

I get no relevant hits in google for those terms. It does not seem to be a [Goliath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goliath_tracked_mine).

What are these things? Any additional info available?

Comment: [This one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borgward_IV) perhaps?

Comment: Yes, probably. B->P is not a huge step. There are more pics on the German version of the page, but have not found a perfect match.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is indeed a [Borgward IV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borgward_IV).

> Actual control during an attack was done from an armored fighting vehicle. The original vehicle used was the Panzer III tank. Then the StuG III/G and finally the Tiger IE. These vehicles had added radio equipment and the controller directed the BIV to its target by radio. When it reached the target, the vehicle would drop the charge and leave the danger area.

The picture you have in the frontal view looks unlike the pictures of the Borgward IV. That is because in your picture, the "load" (explosives in this case) is not in place. It was a boxy compartment in front of the vehicle, to be set down and exploded later when the actual vehicle was at a safe distance (unlike SdKfz 302 Goliath or SdKfz 304 Springer).

Google image search brought me to [this](https://en.topwar.ru/57-teletanketka-borgward-iv-sdkfz301.html) page, which has some really nice pictures of the Borgward without it's load and while unloading it. It looks identical.